# Removing a subset from a SuperSet based on a criteria using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have 2 lists, one is the super set and the other is the subset. What I want to do is delete all the items in the superset which are present in the subset based on the ID.

This is what I do at the moment:

```
var newList = new List<Items>();
foreach(var row in superset)
{
  var presentInSubset = subset.Any(r => r.ID == row.ID);

  if(!presentInSubset)
  {
    newList.Add(row)
  }
}

superset = newList;
```

I'm sure there is a shorter way to achieve this rather than doing this using LINQ. Question is, how do I remove a subset from a superset based on some criteria?

Thanks,
-Mike

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
superset.RemoveAll(x => subset.Select(y => y.ID).Contains(x.ID));
```

Comment: +1 now it's working :) This is short, readable and efficient.

Answer (score 3):

```
var cleanList = superSet.Where(s => !subSet.Any(sub => sub.ID == s.ID)).ToList();
```

Try the above. This doesn't change the original list though. It returns a new clean list instead.

Answer (score 2):

Another (efficient) approach is to use `Enumerable.Join`, you need a "left-outer-join" because you want all in super which are not in sub:

```
var inSuper = from iSuper in superset
              join iSub in subset
              on iSuper.ID equals iSub.ID into gj
              from subJoin in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
              where subJoin == null
              select iSuper;
superset = inSuper.ToList();
```

With this sample data:

```
var superset = new List<Items>() { 
    new Items{ID=1}, new Items{ID=2}, new Items{ID=3}, 
};
var subset = new List<Items>() { 
    new Items{ID=1}, new Items{ID=4}, new Items{ID=3}, 
};
```

Only the  one with ID=2 remains since that is not in subset.

Comment: This is by far the most efficient solution. With some simple benchmarking with 5 runs, 30.000 superset elements of which 50% was in subset using a Person model with some properties, it was a whopping 80% faster than solutions from TGH and Botis.